# JQuery String Replacement in Select List

Tags: jquery, replace

I have the following dropdown list being generated from a database query which includes two "dividers" and looks like this:

```
<select id="mySelectList">
    <option value="divider::: --- Popular Brands ---">divider::: --- Popular Brands ---</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="samsung">Samsung</option>
    <option value="divider::: --- All Brands ---">divider::: --- All Brands ---</option>
    <option value="acer">Acer</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
</select>
```

For both occurrences, I would like to replace the option value to be `""` and to remove the string `divider:::` from the option text. So the end result would look like this:

```
<select id="mySelectList">
    <option value="">--- Popular Brands ---</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="samsung">Samsung</option>
    <option value="">--- All Brands ---</option>
    <option value="acer">Acer</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
</select>
```

I'm using jQuery and have this, but the result isn't what I'm trying to acheive.

```
$("#mySelectList option").each(function() {
                $(this).text($(this).html().replace(/divider:::/g, ""));
            });
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than iterating over every `option`, I'd use pattern matching selectors, eg [the starts-with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```js
$('option[value^=divider]').attr('value', '')
    .text(function() {
        return $(this).text().replace('divider::: ', '');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelectList">
    <option value="divider::: --- Popular Brands ---">divider::: --- Popular Brands ---</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="samsung">Samsung</option>
    <option value="divider::: --- All Brands ---">divider::: --- All Brands ---</option>
    <option value="acer">Acer</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
</select>
```